# SetWindowsHookEx with WH_JOURNALRECORD hook in Qt4

Tags: winapi, hook, qt4.8

I am debugging a closed source legacy application that uses Qt 4.8.6
The application developed a problem after an automatic update of Windows 10

When the problem is triggered application (and also whole Windows desktop) stops receiving keyboard and mouse events, but applications continue to run, mouse cursor also moves.

Everything goes back to normal if `Ctrl+Esc` is pressed to open the start menu, until a specific action is done in the application which triggers the problem again.

I traced the problem to Qt's `QWidget::grabMouse()` which is called on a custom widget in the application.

Tracing the execution of `QWidget::grabMouse()` shows that the problem happens when it executes:

```
journalRec = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_JOURNALRECORD, (HOOKPROC)qJournalRecordProc, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
```

Its `qJournalRecordProc` looks like this:

```
    // The procedure does nothing, but is required for mousegrabbing to work
    LRESULT QT_WIN_CALLBACK qJournalRecordProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(journalRec, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

full source of `QWidget.cpp` where all of this is defined can be found [here](https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/v4.8.6/src/gui/kernel/qwidget_win.cpp)

Googling reveals that `SetWindowsHookEx` has special requirements since Vista in order to deter malware from using it. The app seems to fulfill the requirements that I found by googling (signed by trusted certificate although it is using SHA1, installed in "Program Files",...)

**And now for the actual questions:**

1. Why Qt needs `WH_JOURNALRECORD` to perform mousegrabbing? I thought that by using `WH_JOURNALRECORD` the hook procedure gets mouse/keyboard events and this does not affect the individual widgets. I patched `QtGui4.dll` so it does not call `SetWindowsHookEx` (and related Unhook). This fixes the app and does not have any noticeable side effects.
2. Why would using the `WH_JOURNALRECORD` hook in this way stop keyboard/mouse events being delivered? I also set a breakpoint on the hook procedure and it seems that it never gets called. I also rigged the hook procedure so it would crash the app (in case this strange hook behavior messes up the debugger) and the app did not crash which in my opinion confirms that the hook procedure is never called.

All this hooking stuff looks like a real ugly hack...
And apparently Qt developers recognized this since Qt5's implementation does not use `SetWindowsHookEx` anymore...

**Edit (to clarify some comments):**

I already modified QtGui4 library's `grabMouse` to not call `SetWindowsHookEx` and not to call the corresponding `UnhookWindowsHookEx`.
Since the closed source app apparently uses Qt libraries under the commercial license, they made some closed source modifications to Qt, which forced me to actually patch their QtGui4.dll (changing the part which calls the `SetWindowsHookEx` into `NOPs`.

This resolves the problem with the app and produces no noticeable side effects. But I would like to know why Qt developers deemed necessary to put the hook (which does nothing) there in the first place. And what makes it misbehave.

Comment: I don't like the cast on qJournalRecordProc.

Comment: Well... Qt people seem to like it. It is defined as typedef LRESULT (CALLBACK* HOOKPROC)(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); in WinUser.h...

Comment: JournalRecordProc has the same signature... so this should be fine

Comment: If the signature is correct then you don't need a cast. C casts hide calling convention bugs!

Comment: Sure... but this is not my code :) This is Qt framework itself!

Comment: Since the hook code presented isn't supposed to be doing anything (other than installing the hook), what happens if you disable it (if that is an option for you)?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I did exactly that already before posting this question. It solves the problem with the app, but I would like to know why Qt developers decided to put the hook there in the first place and Why it misbehaves on some fully updated Windows 10 systems.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are patching QtGui4.dll but your `SetWindowsHookEx` line contains `GetModuleHandle(0)` indicating that `qJournalRecordProc` is in your .EXE!

Global hooks should be implemented in a .DLL and the correct HINSTANCE should be passed to `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Comment: See Remarks section of MSDN documentation for JournalRecordProc callback: A JournalRecordProc hook procedure does not need to live in a dynamic-link library. A JournalRecordProc hook procedure can live in the application itself.

Comment: Also this is not my SetWindowsHookEx, this is in the implementation of QtGui4.dll, I also thought this might be a problem, but the same code worked fine on older Windows version.

Comment: Well, the issue is that the HINSTANCE it/you are passing is not the module where the callback is located.

Comment: Ok.. just for fun I can try to fix that, but the question remains. Why does it behave in this way? Why does it simply not return an error or crash if the address of the callback is wrong? And why did it work since Windows XP?

Comment: Journal hooks are old, all the way back to 16-bit Windows (IIRC) and there is probably a fair amount of compatibility stuff going on with them to help broken applications. It is also the wrong choice for any kind of live mouse grabbing/monitoring but that is a whole other topic I guess.

Comment: Exactly... But I would still like to know what the Qt people wanted to achieve here. Clearly this is not typical journal hook usage